# Format number input with Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-directive, angular-pipe

In Angular, how would I format the displayed input's value without changing my model value? The value must be displayed with thousand separator (`' '` for FR, and `','` for EN) and with decimal separator (`','` for FR and `'.'` for EN).

The input must be formatted when the value is initialized from data load by the backend.

I've tried something like this:

```
<input class="form-control" name="test"
      [ngModel]="mynumberValue"
      (ngModelChange)="mynumberValue=$event"
      (blur)="someCalculs()"
      required
      NumberFormat
 >
```

with a directive :

```
@Directive({ selector: '[NumberFormat]' }) export class NumberDirective implements DoCheck {

    private el: HTMLInputElement;
    private onLoadCheck = false;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private numberPipe: NumberPipe
    ) {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        // check if value is applied on init
        if (this.el.value) {
            if (!this.onLoadCheck) {
                this.el.value = this.numberPipe.transform(this.el.value);
                this.onLoadCheck = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
    onBlur(value) {
        this.el.value = this.numberPipe.transform(value);
    }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
    onFocus(value) {
        this.el.value = this.numberPipe.parseToNumber(value);
    }
}
```

And a Pipe :

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'number',
    pure: true
})
export class NumberPipe implements PipeTransform {

    @SessionStorage('user')
    currentUser: User;

    transform(input: any, minPrecision = 2, maxPrecision = 5): string {

        if (isNaN(input) || input === null) {
            return 'N/A';
        }

        return new Intl.NumberFormat(this.currentUser.langKey, {
            minimumFractionDigits: minPrecision,
            maximumFractionDigits: maxPrecision
        }).format(input);
    }

    parseToNumber(input: string) {
        if (this.currentUser.langKey === 'fr') {
            return input.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '.');
        }
        return input.replace(',', '');
    }
}
```

But with this solution, my model is not recognized like a number.

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like such an obvious thing for Angular 2+ to do, yet I can't find anything that actually implements this. Did you get anywhere with it?